# Cost effective way to provide static media content

Tags: security, server, bandwidth, cost, static-content

I'd like to be able to deliver around 50MB of static content, either in about 30 individual files up to 10MB or grouped into 3 compressed files, around 5k to 20k times a day.  Ideally I'd like to put some sort of very basic security around providing the data to ensure that a request is from the expected source, but if tossing the security for a big reduction in price is possible then it's an option.

Does anyone have any suggestions other than what I've found:

Google AppEngine is $0.12/GB & I believe has a file size limit of 10MB so I'd have to break the data up a bit.  So a rough calculation would seem to be that this would cost me about $30 to $120 a day.

Or I've seen something like what seems to be just public static content delivery with no type of logic capabilities like Usenet.nl at what I think calculates to about $0.025/GB which would cost me about $6 to $25 a day.

Any idea if I'm going about these calculations right & if there might be a better option for just static content on a decently high volume delivery?  Again some basic security would be great but if cost is greatly reduced without it then I'm up for that.

Comment: Have you checked Amazon s3?

Comment: Thanks, but yeah they look to be about the same as AppEngine - http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ The price changes depending on the volume $.08 to $0.15/GB so I'd probably end up around the same price.

Comment: You might get a better response on serverfault.com

Comment: To confirm, you are looking to serve 50MB of static files (0.05GB) to 20,000 unique visitors every day? (That would be 0.05GB x 20,000 = 1,000GB/day = 31,000GB/month, which is quite a lot.) Are you sure you didn't mean 20,000 times a *month*? Are they CSS/JavaScript files, software downloads, images, video, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need Amazon S3 or Rackspace cloud. Both have calculators to work out how much you'll be spending:

Amazon
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Rackspace
http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing/

I hope that helps!